# Continuity of the function $f=1/x$

Tags: calculus

How do I show that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition?

I have been trying for quite a while now without success.

**My attempts**

Suppose that $\left |x-x_0 \right| < \delta$  for some $\delta >0$ then $\left |f(x)-f(x_0)\right| =\left |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_0} \right|=\left |\frac{x_0-x}{x \cdot x_0} \right | $

But what do I do when x=0?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you did and perhaps someone can point you in the right direction?

Comment: **Note** that zero is not on the domain of the function.

Comment: I just edited my response to show my work. The point x=0 was my problem, thanks for the answer

Comment: @alfred.young. You only have to show that $f$ is continuous at points on the domain. And zero is not there. But if you want to extend the domain defining for example $f(0)=2$ than you can study the continuity at $x=0$. What do you think then?

Comment: If f(0)=2 then it probably won't be continuous for all x as we can get arbitrary large numbers for f(x) at x close to 0

Comment: @alfred.young Just for completeness $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (which means the closure is the whole set), so if there is a continuous extension in zero it is unique (due to the hausdorff property of $\mathbb{R}$. This won't work. Or a less topological arguement is, that every continuous function is locally bounded (this is a direct result of $\varepsilon- \delta$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume we are looking at the fuction $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$. A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous in $x$ iff 
\[ \forall \varepsilon >0 \exists \delta > 0 : \forall y\in X \text{ with }  |x-y|< \delta \text{ the following holds } |f(x)-f(y)|< \varepsilon\]

A function is continuous if it is continuous in every point of its domain. 
Now lets take a look at $|f(x)-f(y)|$

\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)|&= | \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}| \\
&= |\frac{y-x}{xy}| \\
&= |x-y| \cdot \frac{1}{|xy|}
\end{align*}

This doesn't look that helpfull, but now we make a little trick. We say that $\delta < \frac{|x|}{2}$, now you know that $\frac{|x|}{2} \leq y\leq \frac{3|x|}{2}$ now you can bound those and you are done-

Comment: Thanks! Marking it as the answer

Comment: Let me suggest a small correction: in the definition of continuity, where you write "$|x-y|<\delta \implies\ldots$", instead it should be "$|x-y| < \delta$ and $y$ in the domain of $f \implies \ldots$". This clears up all confusions regarding $0$: neither $x$ nor $y$ will ever be chosen to be equal to $0$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Edited, I hope it is better now